# How to display dynamic text

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I am new to react native and I am trying to build an app that simulates a basic dialer. What I am having trouble with is displaying the numbers that I click.

For example, this is my function to add '1' to the display

```
var number = '';
const tlac1 = function(){
  var add_one = '1';
  number = number + add_one;
  console.log(number);
};
```

and this is how I am trying to display it:

```
<View style={styles.display}>
  <Text>{number}</Text>
</View>
```

Can anyone please explain to me why is the showing text not updated? When I am pressing 1 it does update and shows correct numbers in consoler, however it does not do the same with displaying it in Text element.

My whole component:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.display}>
          <Text>{number}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.keys}>
            <View style={styles.inner}>
              <Pressable onPress={tlac1}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 40, fontWeight: '200'}}>1</Text> 
              </Pressable>
            </View>
        </View>
</View>
```

Comment: what does your whole component look like?

Comment: normally, your component would have a state, and when you call `this.tlac1` it would do `this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 })`, something like that, and then in your render function you would have `<Text>{this.state.number}</Text>`

Comment: It would be slightly different but similar principles if it's a functional component

Comment: @TKoL I provided you with my whole component

Comment: there's gotta be code surrounding it. Is it in a class or a function? where's the rest of it?

Comment: It is inside a class under render()

Comment: right, so your class should have a constructor function, and in that constructor function you can set the state, `this.state = { number: 1 }`, and then you can update the state with `this.setState` as I described before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how a similar component would be described in HTML-based react code:

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        number: 1
    }
    
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
  }
  
  increment() {
    this.setState({number: this.state.number + 1})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.number} />
        <button onClick={this.increment}>increment</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, you set the state initially in the constructor and then use the `increment` function to modify the state, by using `this.setState`

The exact same principles will apply in react-native.

Not sure what your setup is like, but make sure your handling the `this.<function>.bind(this)` situation somehow